# Shifting the x axis with the ggsurvfit package without cutting the risk table

Tags: r, survival-analysis, ggsurvfit

When I shift the x-axis of the ggplot using scale_x_continuous, the values in the first column of the risk table are partially covered.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggsurvfit)

p <- 
  survfit2(Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data = df_lung) %>%
  ggsurvfit(linewidth = 1) + 
  scale_ggsurvfit() + 
  add_risktable(
    risktable_stats = c("n.risk")) +
  theme_classic()+
  scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0, 1), limits = c(0, 34), breaks = seq(0, 30, 6))


p
```

[image]

How to move the x-axis without cropping part of the risk table?

Comment: When you add `scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0, 1))` you're cutting off the numbers in the risk table by reducing the padding too much. You can either reduce the font size in the risk table, or increase the padding on the left side of the x-axis by midifying your `expand=` values.

Answer (score 4):

Using base R, you could use the original `survival` package, `aggregate` the survival table by strata from the fit and add it as `text`. The `plot` will come with specific `axTicks(1)` whih we will use for `summary` and x-positions. Using `xpd=TRUE` allows using `text` outside plotting region.

```
> library(survival)
> fit <- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data=transform(lung, sex=factor(sex, labels=c('Male', 'Female'))))
> par(mar=c(8, 4, 1, 1)+.1, xpd=TRUE)
> plot(fit, col=c(2, 4))
> (tb <- with(summary(fit, time=axTicks(1)), aggregate(n.risk ~ strata, FUN=I)$n.risk) |>
+     sapply(`length<-`, length(axTicks(1))) |> apply(2, \(x) replace(x, is.na(x), 0)) |>
+     `colnames<-`(names(fit$strata)) |> round(2))
     sex=Male sex=Female
[1,]      138         90
[2,]       78         66
[3,]       31         26
[4,]       13         11
[5,]        6          2
[6,]        2          0
> legend('topright', legend=names(fit$strata), lwd=1, col=c(2, 4))
> text(-10, -.4, labels='At Risk', adj=1, cex=.9)
> Map(text, x=list(axTicks(1)), y=c(-0.55, -0.65), labels=asplit(tb, 2), cex=.8)
[[1]]
NULL

[[2]]
NULL

> Map(text, x=-150, y=c(-0.55, -0.65), labels=gsub('sex=', '', names(fit$strata)), 
+     adj=0, cex=.8)
[[1]]
NULL

[[2]]
NULL
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

One potential option is change the horizontal justification:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggsurvfit)

p <- 
  survfit2(Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data = df_lung) %>%
  ggsurvfit(linewidth = 1) + 
  scale_ggsurvfit() + 
  theme_classic()+
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0,0), limits = c(0, 34), breaks = seq(0, 30, 6)) +
  add_risktable(
    risktable_stats = c("n.risk")
  )
#> Scale for x is already present.
#> Adding another scale for x, which will replace the existing scale.
p
```

[image]

```r
# with hjust = 1, instead of the default 0.5
p2 <- 
  survfit2(Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data = df_lung) %>%
  ggsurvfit(linewidth = 1) + 
  scale_ggsurvfit() + 
  theme_classic()+
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(0, 34), breaks = seq(0, 30, 6)) +
  add_risktable(
    risktable_stats = c("n.risk"),
    hjust = 0
    )
#> Scale for x is already present.
#> Adding another scale for x, which will replace the existing scale.
p2
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-01-16 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

The numbers don't really line up though. Maybe if you adjusted the x axis text?

```r
p3 <- 
  survfit2(Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data = df_lung) %>%
  ggsurvfit(linewidth = 1) + 
  scale_ggsurvfit() + 
  theme_classic()+
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(0, 34), breaks = seq(0, 30, 6)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(hjust = 0)) +
  add_risktable(
    risktable_stats = c("n.risk"),
    hjust = 0
    )
#> Scale for x is already present.
#> Adding another scale for x, which will replace the existing scale.
p3
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-01-16 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Not sure if this is what you're after, but, if not, it's probably best to go with @jay.sf's 'fully customisable' approach

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I saved the ggplot in *.EPS format as curves and edited it in a graphics program, moving the y-axis and y-axis labels to position 0, achieving the intended effect.

[image]